# Resource recommendation for Kogut-Susskind Hamiltonian formalism for lattice gauge theory

Tags: resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, lattice-gauge-theory

Recently, quantum simulations for quantum field theories have been a hot topic of research. In these calculations, the lattice calculations are done using the Hamiltonian formalism in contrast to the traditional Lagrangian/path-integral approach. However, I have not found an elaborate/introductory account of the Hamiltonian formalism except the two original papers that everyone cites:

[Review by Kogut (1979)](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.51.659)

[Original paper by Susskind and Kogut (1975)](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.11.395)

These two articles are old and concise. Is there any recent more explanatory version of the Hamiltonian formalism of the lattice gauge theory with examples/applications?